# call wcf service using dojo xhr post

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, wcf, dojo

I've been able to call methodes in my .Net wcf service using dojo xhr.get, but now I need to use xhr post to pass a class to a method in the same wcf service.  when I use the following the parameter is null when it reaches my .Net Method:

dojo xhr call:

```
AirVacInspectionInsert: function (url, av) {//url is valid, av is javascript object identical to class input parameter for .Net method validated json format
        xhr.post({//send data
            url: url,
            postData: dojo.toJson(av),
            contentType: "application/json",
            handleAs: "json",
            load: function (result) {
                var InspDataID = result.AirVacInspectionInsertResult;

            },
            error: function (err) { }

        });
```

.Net:
Interface:

```
 [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        UriTemplate = "AirVacInspectionInsert/")]
        int AirVacInspectionInsert(AVInspectionData av);
```

.Net Method:

```
  public int AirVacInspectionInsert(AVInspectionData av)//av is null
         {
             //insert new air vac inspection
            int ID = 0;
            //DataSet ds = DBCalls.AirVacInspectionInsert(av);
            //ID = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]);
            return ID;
         }
```

Web.config:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="SARIService.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="SARIService.IService1"     behaviorConfiguration="web">

        </endpoint>

      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
        </behavior>

      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>

  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Any ideas?  Is there some parameter I'm missing to get the service to read the posted data?

Thanks

Comment: I made a type on my uri template property of the interface.  The uri template should be:  UriTemplate = "AirVacInspectionInsert")] not UriTemplate = "AirVacInspectionInsert/")].  This doesnt solve the problem though -- still doesnt read the posted data

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the .Net interface.  I changed

```
 BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
```

to

```
 BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
```

and it worked